# How to add multiple realms?

Tags: azerothcore

With an existing `authserver` and `worldserver` in Ubuntu 18.04, how can I add a second `worldserver` (realm) to their setup? Does it require a completely new CMAKE or can you just copy and paste the folders?

Answer (score 1):

As you might have guessed, you need one `worldserver` process per every realm. So to add another realm, you need to run one more `worldserver`.

A `worldserver` needs:

- its own `acore_world` database
- its own `acore_character` database
- the `acore_auth` will be shared across all realms, so you need only one of it
- its own `worldserver.conf` file. Because of this, you have to recompile and pass a different path for the configuration file (so a different `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`)

Then you can open the new `worldserver.conf` and configure it with:

- put a different port for `WorldServerPort`
- the new databases (`WorldDatabaseInfo` and `CharacterDatabaseInfo`)
- and of course, you can change other configurations as you please

If I remember correctly, you can set your `worldserver.conf` A and `worldserver.conf` B to share the same data files (`DataDir` - tip: always put an absolute path here).

Lastly, you have to update your `acore_auth.realmlist` table by adding the new realm and its port.

Comment: do the database names have to be the same or can i change that up?
so i could do cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/azeroth-server2/ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -DTOOLS=0 -DSCRIPTS=1

Comment: - first answer: MySQL will NOT allow you to create 2 databases with the same name. So yes, they have to have different names.